# Derivative of capital Pi and Sigma

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I calculate the derivative of $f(x)=\prod_{i = 1}^{18} (r_i-x)$. I know that we can take the derivative of sigma by brining the operator inside but how do I calculate $f'(3)$ for example? My professor told me that we could do it without listing all the products so that there must be a way. But I haven't figured it out.

Can I just say that $f'(x)=\prod_{i = 1}^{18} (r_i-1)$ is the derivative?

Can someone find the $f'(3) or f'(5)$ so I can get a general idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{18}(r_i-x)$ the product rule tells you to differentiate each term, multiply by the rest, and add the results.  The derivative of $r_i-x$ is just $-1$, so the piece coming from differentiating term $i$ is just $-1\cdot \frac{f(x)}{r_i-x}$ and the overall answer is 
$$f'(x)=-\sum_{i=1}^{18} \frac {f(x)}{r_i-x}$$
Note that $\frac {f(x)}{r_i-x}$ is just the product of the $17$ factors other than $r_i-x$

Answer (score 1):

You can take logarithms to turn the product into a sum. This isn't entirely legitimate, because you can't take the logarithm of a non-positive number, but it does work here - and if you are more comfortable differentiating sums than products it can give you a good indication of what to expect, or a check on your workings. After all in the places where taking logarithms is legitimate, the derivative has to be the same however it is computed.

First write $$\ln f(x) = \sum \ln (r_i-x)$$

Now you can differentiate a sum $$\frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}=-\sum\frac 1{r_i-x}$$ and finally $$f'(x)=-f(x)\sum \frac 1{r_i-x}$$

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the generalised product rule.
Keep in mind that $(uv)' = uv' + u'v$
Furthermore we got $(uvw)' = uv'w + u'vw + uvw'$

Or in general:

$$\dfrac{d}{dx} \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x)\right) = \left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} f_i(x)\right) \cdot \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n} \dfrac{f_i'(x)}{f_i(x)}\right) $$

A very short proof has been done on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule#A_product_of_more_than_two_factors):